# IoC.Resolve deep in the project or Constructor Injection on entry point of app

Tags: c#, object-oriented, .net, dependency-injection

I'm building cross-platform application (every mobile/desktop OS + web in ASP.NET). I'm using Xamarin, so I can do everything in C#. But before I start working on UIs, I want to build soild, flexible **Core/Domain** project that will be shared in all Client apps.

I read a lot about DI and IoC containers, I know a lot of theory, but when it comes to coding I'm confused and sometimes I've a feeling I have no idea what am I doing.

**Quickly about my app:** It will be simple game, like tic tac toe. But I want to do it as flexible as possible, so it will be easy to build on top of it another games, like: connect four or reversi or even chess. Simple 2 players board games.

My concerns are about my "DI-friendly" implementation and the way of using IoC container. My project has 3 main layers: UI<-API<-Domain(Entites). In UI I need to create `IGame` object. Game has its `GameType` (just an enum), `List<IPlayers>` and `IBoard`.

**My question(s) are:**

- **Should I resolve my interfaces in one place?** Good example is `IBoard` in my project. It is needed and used only deep in `Game` object. `Game` obviously depends on `IBoard`. So as I read it'd be good practice to inject `IBoard` through constoructor - so it's clear: *"Game depends on Board"*. But this way, I create `Board` instance in UI, then I have to pass it to `GameAPI`, then to `GameFactory` and finally to `Game` object. I could easily create it or **resolve it** in `Game` constructor, without passing through every layer in application.
- **Where exactly should I resolve my interfaces?** Should it be on very top in UI? Should it be in one place? Where should I create/resolve my `IBoard`?

I did't want to paste here fragments of code and force you to paste it back to IDE, so I've made *"Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example"* and put it [here](https://github.com/toddenglewood/tictactoe).

**Here's my UI:**

```
namespace Tictactoe.UI
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {   
        private  GameAPI GameAPI { get; } = new GameAPI();
        private  IGame CurrentGame { get; set; }
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();    

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();    

            // Load all dependencies
            var modules = new List<INinjectModule> { new TictactoeModule() };
            kernel.Load(modules);
        }    

        private void buttonNewGameSingle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StartNewGame(GameType.SinglePlayer);
        }    

        private void buttonNewTwoPlayers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StartNewGame(GameType.TwoPlayers);
        }    

        private void buttonNewGameOnline_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StartNewGame(GameType.Online);
        }    

        private void StartNewGame(GameType type)
        {
            EnableBoard(true);
            ResetBoard();    

            // Without IoC
            //IPlayerFactory playerFactory = new PlayerFactory(); // Resolve player facotry
            //IGameFactory gameFactory = new GameFactory(playerFactory); // Resolve game facotry
            //IBoard board = new Board(3,3); // Resolve board    

            // With IoC
            IPlayerFactory playerFactory = kernel.Get<IPlayerFactory>();
            IGameFactory gameFactory = kernel.Get<IGameFactory>(new ConstructorArgument("playerFactory", playerFactory));
            IBoard board = kernel.Get<IBoard>(new ConstructorArgument("width", 3), new ConstructorArgument("height", 3));    

            CurrentGame = GameAPI.CreateGame(gameFactory, type, board);
        }    

        private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button clicked = sender as Button;
            if (clicked != null)
            {
                int[] xy;
                buttons.TryGetValue(clicked.Name, out xy);    

                Console.WriteLine(clicked.Name + "[" + xy[0] + "," + xy[1] + "]");

                if (CurrentGame.IsMoveValid(xy[0], xy[1]))
                {
                    IMove result = CurrentGame.MakeMove(xy[0], xy[1]);
                    clicked.Text = result.PlayerId.ToString();
                    if (result.IsConnected)
                    {
                        EnableBoard(false);
                        MessageBox.Show("Finished! Player " + result.PlayerId + " won!");
                    }
                    else if (result.IsGameOver)
                    {
                        EnableBoard(false);
                        MessageBox.Show("Game over!!");
                    }
                }
            }
        }    

        #region UI Helpers    

        private Dictionary<string, int[]> buttons = new Dictionary<string, int[]>
        {
            { "button1", new[] {0, 0} },
            { "button2", new[] {0, 1} },
            { "button3", new[] {0, 2} },
            { "button4", new[] {1, 0} },
            { "button5", new[] {1, 1} },
            { "button6", new[] {1, 2} },
            { "button7", new[] {2, 0} },
            { "button8", new[] {2, 1} },
            { "button9", new[] {2, 2} }
        };    

        private void EnableBoard(bool enable)
        {
            button1.Enabled = enable;
            button2.Enabled = enable;
            button3.Enabled = enable;
            button4.Enabled = enable;
            button5.Enabled = enable;
            button6.Enabled = enable;
            button7.Enabled = enable;
            button8.Enabled = enable;
            button9.Enabled = enable;
        }    

        private void ResetBoard()
        {
            button1.Text = string.Empty;
            button2.Text = string.Empty;
            button3.Text = string.Empty;
            button4.Text = string.Empty;
            button5.Text = string.Empty;
            button6.Text = string.Empty;
            button7.Text = string.Empty;
            button8.Text = string.Empty;
            button9.Text = string.Empty;
        }    

        #endregion    


    }
}
```

**Here's my `DependencyResolver`:**

```
namespace Tictactoe.DependencyResolver
{
    public class TictactoeModule : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<IPlayerFactory>().To<PlayerFactory>();
            Bind<IGameFactory>().To<GameFactory>();
            Bind<IBoard>().To<Board>();
        }
    }
}
```

**Here's my API. UI uses only API methods.**

```
namespace TicTactoe.API
{
    public class GameAPI
    {
        public IGame CurrentGame { get; set; }    

        public IGame CreateGame(IGameFactory gameFactory, GameType type, IBoard board)
        {
            CurrentGame = gameFactory.CreateGame(type, board);
            return CurrentGame;
        }    

        public IMove MakeMove(int row, int column)
        {
            if (CurrentGame == null) return null;
            return CurrentGame.MakeMove(row, column);
        }    

        //TODO: Online player move, or bot
    }
}
```

**And finally, my Domain. My interfaces:**

```
    public interface IBoard
    {
        int Width { get; set; }
        int Height { get; set; }
        int[,] Fields { get; set; }
        int WinnerId { get; set; }    

        void Reset();
        bool IsMoveValid(int row, int column, int playerId);
        IMove InsertChip(int row, int column, int playerId);
    }    

    public interface IGame
    {
        GameType Type { get; }
        IBoard Board { get; }
        List<IPlayer> Players { get; }    

        bool IsMoveValid(int row, int column);
        IMove MakeMove(int row, int column);
    }    

    public interface IGameFactory
    {
        IGame CreateGame(GameType type, IBoard board);
    }    

    public interface IMove
    {
        int PlayerId { get; set; }
        bool IsConnected { get; }
        bool IsGameOver { get; }
    }    

    public interface IPlayer
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
        string Name { get; set; }
        PlayerType Type { get; set; }
    }    

    public interface IPlayerFactory
    {
        IPlayer CreatePlayer(PlayerType type, int id);
    }
```

**And my implementation in Domain:**

```
namespace Tictactoe.Domain
{
    public class Game : IGame
    {
        private int currentPlayerIndex = 1;    

        public Game(GameType type, IBoard board, List<IPlayer> players)
        {
            Type = type;
            Board = board;
            Players = players;
        }    

        public GameType Type { get; }
        public IBoard Board { get; }
        public List<IPlayer> Players { get; }    

        public bool IsMoveValid(int row, int column)
        {
            // It could be done entierly here. Just doing what Board now is doing: if (Board.Fields[row, column] == 0) return true; 
            // But there can be much more things to do in more complicated games, so I'm not sure about that
            // I left that job in Board class, and just call it.    

            if (Players[currentPlayerIndex - 1].Type.Equals(PlayerType.Human))
            {
                return Board.IsMoveValid(row, column, currentPlayerIndex);
            }    

            //if current player is Bot or Online player, your move is not allowed
            return false;
        }    

        public IMove MakeMove(int row, int column)
        {
            IMove result = Board.InsertChip(row, column, currentPlayerIndex);    

            // Set next player
            if (!result.IsConnected) currentPlayerIndex = currentPlayerIndex == 1 ? 2 : 1;    

            return result;
        }
    }
}    

namespace Tictactoe.Domain
{
    public class Board : IBoard
    {
        public int Width { get; set; }
        public int Height { get; set; }
        public int[,] Fields { get; set; }
        public int WinnerId { get; set; }    

        public Board(int width, int height)
        {
            Width = width;
            Height = height;
            Reset();
        }    

        public void Reset()
        {
            Fields = new int[Width,Height];
            for (int i = 0; i < Fields.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < Fields.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    Fields[i, j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }    

        public bool IsMoveValid(int row, int column, int playerId)
        {
            // There will much more work to do in more complicated games
            if (Fields[row, column] == 0) return true;
            return false;
        }    

        public IMove InsertChip(int row, int column, int playerId)
        {
            bool success = false;
            bool gameOver = true;
            Fields[row, column] = playerId;    

            // Very bad, I know. But it's just quick temp solution:
            if (Fields[0, 0].Equals(playerId) && Fields[0, 1].Equals(playerId) && Fields[0, 2].Equals(playerId)) success = true;
            if (Fields[1, 0].Equals(playerId) && Fields[1, 1].Equals(playerId) && Fields[1, 2].Equals(playerId)) success = true;
            if (Fields[2, 0].Equals(playerId) && Fields[2, 1].Equals(playerId) && Fields[2, 2].Equals(playerId)) success = true;    

            if (Fields[0, 0].Equals(playerId) && Fields[1, 0].Equals(playerId) && Fields[2, 0].Equals(playerId)) success = true;
            if (Fields[0, 1].Equals(playerId) && Fields[1, 1].Equals(playerId) && Fields[2, 1].Equals(playerId)) success = true;
            if (Fields[0, 2].Equals(playerId) && Fields[1, 2].Equals(playerId) && Fields[2, 2].Equals(playerId)) success = true;    

            if (Fields[0, 0].Equals(playerId) && Fields[1, 1].Equals(playerId) && Fields[2, 2].Equals(playerId)) success = true;
            if (Fields[0, 2].Equals(playerId) && Fields[1, 1].Equals(playerId) && Fields[2, 0].Equals(playerId)) success = true;    

            // Check if there any valid move has left
            if (Fields.Cast<int>().Any(field => field == 0)) gameOver = false;

            return new Move(playerId, success, gameOver);
        }
    }
}    

namespace Tictactoe.Domain
{
    // Separate class for Move result, because in more compilcated games, 
    // there could be more info to pass.
    // Even here, UI would like to know how fields are connected (when won) - to show it (painting the line or sth)
    public class Move : IMove
    {
        public int PlayerId { get; set; }
        public bool IsConnected { get; }
        public bool IsGameOver { get; }    

        public Move(int playerId, bool isConnected, bool isGameOver = false)
        {
            PlayerId = playerId;
            IsConnected = isConnected;
            IsGameOver = isGameOver;
        }
    }
}    

namespace Tictactoe.Domain
{
    public class Player : IPlayer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public PlayerType Type { get; set; }    

        public Player(PlayerType type, int id)
        {
            Type = type;
            Id = id;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Should I resolve my interfaces in one place? "

Yes. This is called a [composition root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277771/what-is-a-composition-root-in-the-context-of-dependency-injection). You should *definitely not* use your IOC container as a service locator. This is considered [an antipattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) and also really just removes the point of inversion of control; instead of getting dependency injection, you're *really* just creating an abstracted monolithic factory instead.

The article I linked above ([here again just in case](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/)) actually has a lot of good information on how you can abuse dependency injection frameworks as service locators and why it is a bad idea, but here's a relevant excerpt from it..

> ```
> public class OrderProcessor : IOrderProcessor
> {
>     public void Process(Order order)
>     {
>         var validator = Locator.Resolve<IOrderValidator>();
>         if (validator.Validate(order))
>         {
>             var shipper = Locator.Resolve<IOrderShipper>();
>             shipper.Ship(order);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Okay, so the class has a default constructor. That means I can simply
>   create a new instance of it and invoke the Process method right away:
>
> ```
> var order = new Order();
> var sut = new OrderProcessor();
> sut.Process(order);
> ```
>
> Alas, running this code surprisingly throws a KeyNotFoundException
>   because the IOrderValidator was never registered with Locator. This is
>   not only surprising, it may be quite baffling if we don't have access
>   to the source code.

Comment: Thanks! So, your're saying that my code is ok, right? I resolve everything in my UI, right after user click "New Game". In my situation *composition root* is `Game.cs` it takes: `GameType `, `IBoard` and `List<IPlayer>`. Those 3 are needed to create `Game` and start playing. I use abstract factory - so `GameFactory` takes everything that's needed to create game. `GameFactory` is used by `GameAPI`, so `GameAPI` takes everything that's need to build `Game`. That way I create/resolve everything I need at the very beginning in UI. Is my solution correct?

Comment: Theoretically I could resolve only `IBoard` via constructor + pass `GameType`. Then, `List<IPlayer>` I can resolve via setter. I'm still not sure about that idea tho

Answer (score 6):

My emphasis:

> Where exactly should I resolve my interfaces? **Should it be on very top in UI?** Should it be in one place? Where should I create/resolve my IBoard?

The UI is only at the very top if you put it there because a WinForms application template normally looks like this:

> ```
> static class Program
> {
>     /// <summary>
>     /// The main entry point for the application.
>     /// </summary>
>     [STAThread]
>     static void Main()
>     {
>         Application.EnableVisualStyles();
>         Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
>         Application.Run(new Form1());
>     }
> }
> ```

This code is exactly like this, untouched, unchanged, in your GitHub repository.

If there's *one place* to implement a *composition root*, it's right here - that's the *actual* entry point, it doesn't get any higher-to-the-top than that. It's where the first `new` statement creates the first object in the application, a `Form1` instance. Form closes, `Main` reaches its closing brace, program ends.

There's a dependency on [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms) here, with the `System.Windows.Forms.Application`. Then with the `Form` type `Form1` is derived from.

If this is our *composition root*, then we need 3 things to happen:

- Register
- Resolve
- Release

"Register" is the configuration part, which you correctly handled in `NinjectModule` objects.

"Resolve" is when you call `Get<T>()` to fetch an instance of something from the container.

"Release" has been overlooked, but it's no big deal since no `IDisposable` object is involved here. Well, except the `IKernel` itself, which you're *not* disposing, but then, when the form closes the app terminates anyway. Still, best practice would be to dispose of disposables.

Ayway you're doing the "register" part in the constructor:

> ```
> public Form1()
> {
>     InitializeComponent();
>
>     // Load all dependencies
>     var modules = new List<INinjectModule> { new TictactoeModule() };
>     kernel.Load(modules);
> }
> ```

Which means `kernel.Load(modules);` is called by the WinForms designer. There's a reason why a `Form` needs a public parameterless constructor that calls `InitializeComponent`: *the designer calls it*.

Here there's a `new StandardKernel()` being instantiated, so `Form1` is *tightly coupled* with `StandardKernel`, no matter how pretty having an `IKernel` private field looks.

So how do you constructor-inject anything into a `Form` without breaking the designer? You chain your parameterized constructor with the default/parameterless one.

```
private readonly IKernel _kernel; // smells...

/// <summary>
/// Default constructor required for designer.
/// </summary>
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

/// <summary>
/// Default constructor required for designer.
/// </summary>
public Form1(IKernel kernel) // ah-ha! service locator!
    : this() // need to ensure default constructor runs...
             // ...the alternative is to duplicate the InitializeComponent() call.
{
    _kernel = kernel; 
}
```

Notice that the type is now receiving the IoC container as a dependency, through its constructor. Yes, as an abstraction/interface, but the thing with passing the IoC container around as a dependency, is that you've just defeated the entire purpose of DI/IoC: you've leaked the dependency on your IoC container into your application, and now you have business code that needs an IoC container to *work*.

Dependency Injection doesn't need an IoC container. Let's see what we're resolving with that `kernel`.

> ```
> // Without IoC
> //IPlayerFactory playerFactory = new PlayerFactory(); // Resolve player facotry
> //IGameFactory gameFactory = new GameFactory(playerFactory); // Resolve game facotry
> //IBoard board = new Board(3,3); // Resolve board
>
> // With IoC
> IPlayerFactory playerFactory = kernel.Get<IPlayerFactory>();
> IGameFactory gameFactory = kernel.Get<IGameFactory>(new ConstructorArgument("playerFactory", playerFactory));
> IBoard board = kernel.Get<IBoard>(new ConstructorArgument("width", 3), new ConstructorArgument("height", 3));
> ```

Interesting. Which one is better? Neither. That's not how you use an IoC container. If you've read the theory of DI/IoC, you must have read about...

> ## Don't call them, they'll call you.
>
> ***The Hollywood Principle***

Well an IoC container is like Hollywood. You don't call an IoC container. It calls you. Sounds backwards? That's why it's called *inversion* of control!

Code that does DI correctly, could be recompiled with a new *composition root* that's using a new IoC framework, and there wouldn't be anything to change in the business code. Nothing. Not even a single instruction.

Unless you've registered them `InSingletonScope()`, you're resolving a new `IPlayerFactory` and a new `IGameFactory` instance every time a new game starts; *resolving* stands for *resolving dependencies*, so `Form1` has dependencies on `IGameFactory` and `IPlayerFactory`. But hold on:

> ```
> CurrentGame = GameAPI.CreateGame(gameFactory, type, board);
> ```

The `IGameFactory` instance is actually a dependency of the `GameAPI` class!

> ```
> private  GameAPI GameAPI { get; } = new GameAPI();
> ```

There: `GameAPI` is another type that's *strongly coupled* with `Form1`. And this `new` means something isn't right. Every time you `new` something up, you fail Dependency Injection.

The `GameAPI` class has no constructor, but exposes this `CreateGame` method:

> ```
> public IGame CurrentGame { get; set; }
>
> public IGame CreateGame(IGameFactory gameFactory, GameType type, IBoard board)
> {
>     CurrentGame = gameFactory.CreateGame(type, board);
>     return CurrentGame;
> }
> ```

So you have a reference to the `CurrentGame` in two places - in `Form1`, and then in `GameAPI`. And `Form1` has a dependency on `GameAPI`, so you could do this:

> ```
> CurrentGame = GameAPI.CreateGame(gameFactory, type, board);
> ```

Or that:

```
private readonly GameAPI _api = new GameAPI();
private IGame CurrentGame { get { return _api.CurrentGame; } }
```

Or, actually, just this:

```
private readonly GameAPI _api = new GameAPI();
```

And use `_api.CurrentGame` instead of having two references to the same object.

But the main problem I'm seeing here is that `MakeMove` is also calling into `CurrentGame`: the class is just an excuse for that `CreateGame` method that not only creates an `IGame` object and returns it, it also sets the `CurrentGame` as an undocumented side-effect.

Get rid of that `GameAPI` class, it smells.

So what should the `Form1` constructor look like then? What are the *real* dependencies?

- `IPlayerFactory` is only ever used as a constructor argument for `IGameFactory`.
- `IGameFactory` is only ever used to create an `IGame`.
- `IBoard` is only ever used as a parameter for the `IGameFactory`.

The `StartNewGame` method is called by 3 of the buttons on the form, each passing in a different `GameType` enum value.

"Start new game" sounds an awful lot like a job for a game factory - well done! Looking at the usages for the `IGame CurrentGame` it creates, the game is actually implemented inside a `button_Click` handler - but I'll get back to that. I was talking about the constructor.

The factories could be simplified.

At first glance the dependency on `IPlayerFactory` isn't real, and `GameType` isn't *really* needed either. Consider:

```
public class GameFactory : IGameFactory
{
    public IGame Create(IBoard board, IEnumerable<IPlayer> players)
    {
        return new Game(board, players);
    }
}
```

Turns out a factory that's as simple as that can be 100% handled by Ninject's *Factory* extension, like this:

```
Bind<IGameFactory>().ToFactory();
```

Boom. Done. At runtime you get a proxy type that implements `IGameFactory` and passes the `Create` method's parameters into the constructor of whatever type is registered for an `IGame`: you never ever need to actually implement an *Abstract Factory* with a concrete type ever again.

It would also work if the `GameFactory` class had an `IPlayerFactory` dependency like your implementation does, but it's a false dependency that is obscuring things - and that's how you get an `IGameFactory` that returns `IPlayer` objects.

Your `IPlayerFactory` itself is flawless - I would only have left it to Ninject to implement the concrete type on the fly. The problem isn't the `IPlayerFactory`, it's where the dependency is. It makes no sense for an `IGameFactory` to create anything other than `IGame` objects; that's why I'm leaving it up to whoever is calling `Create` to supply an `IEnumerable<IPlayer>`, because you don't *really* care what `IGame.Type` is - you're exposing it as a getter, but it's not used anywhere, it just pollutes the `IGame` interface.

So, that constructor.

```
private readonly IGameFactory _gameFactory;

public Form1(IGameFactory gameFactory, IPlayerFactory playerFactory) : this()
{
    _gameFactory = gameFactory; 
    _playerFactory = playerFactory;
}
```

Now the button click handlers don't need to pass a `GameType` anymore, they just call `_playerFactory.Create` to create the players required, and then pass the created players to `_gameFactory.Create` to create the `IGame`, at least for now.

---

#### Register.

The registration code could be simplified, using the `Ninject.Extensions.Conventions` extension - that way you can give yourself a naming convention and define it, and then whatever interfaces you add to your project are automatically handled. For example you could make a convention that says "bind all interfaces for all classes in all assemblies of the solution except those with a name ending with 'Factory'" -- and then make another convention that says "bind all interfaces with a name ending with 'Factory' to a Ninject factory.", like this:

```
var assemblies = new[]
{
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(),
    Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(IGame)),
};

Bind<Form1>().ToSelf();

Bind(t => t.From(assemblies)
           .SelectAllClasses()
           .Where(type => !type.Name.EndsWith("Factory"))
           .BindAllInterfaces());

Bind(t => t.From(assemblies)
           .SelectAllInterfaces()
           .Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("Factory"))
           .BindToFactory());

Rebind<IBoard>().To<Board>()
                .WithConstructorArgument("width", 3)
                .WithConstructorArgument("height", 3);
```

And then you can pretty much leave that NinjectModule implementation alone for a while ;-)

#### Resolve.

The composition root would look like this:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Load(new TicTacToeModule()); // register

        var mainForm = kernel.Get<Form1>(); // resolve
        Start(mainForm);

        kernel.Dispose(); // release
    }

    static void Start(Form mainForm)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(mainForm);
    }
}
```

As you see, there's really only 1 `kernel.Get<T>` call you need to make, to resolve the `mainForm` object and with it, the entire dependency graph of the application. Here's the same code without an IoC container:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        var board = new Board(3, 3);
        var gameFactory = new GameFactory(board);
        var playerFactory = new PlayerFactory();
        var mainForm = new Form1(gameFactory, playerFactory);

        Start(mainForm);
    }

    static void Start(Form mainForm)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(mainForm);
    }
}
```

A few points:

- All `new`ing up is happening at the composition root whether there's an IoC container or not.
- An application that size hardly benefits from an IoC container - "poor man's DI" makes code easier to follow; introduce an IoC container when manually newing things up becomes more painful than configuring the container.

---

I'll stop here for this answer, but refactoring of the code should go further than that: the logic that's in the click handlers belongs in the `Game` class, which means the factories probably belong there as well. But when you get to that point, you'll be ready for a new follow-up post anyway.

Don't give up!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32025/discussion-on-answer-by-mats-mug-ioc-resolve-deep-in-the-project-or-constructor).